# How to add randomize row values in php without repeatition

Tags: php, mysql

from the past few days i have had this problem with a quiz scenario in created as part of my project. i wanted random questions to be asked but when i use the rand() function , the questions are being repeated. also i figured out that since its being done on the same page and every time the page refreshes, the random number is again selected thereby leading to this flaw! so i considered storing the value of the last random que_id in a session and generating a query like so:

```
enter code here <?php session_start();$jsqla=mysql_query("select que_id from mst_que");$jfeta=mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);session_start();$id=array($jfeta['id$_SESSION['id'][] = $id;$rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mst_que` WHERE que_id NOTIN ('id') ORDER BY RAND() ")
```

Please help me in this. I just want to create a session array where i want to store the previously generated random number and use it in query so that it is not repeated again. please

Comment: `NOTIN` is a typo. The syntax is `NOT IN()`.

Comment: no idea why you're starting the session twice.

Comment: Don't repeatedly pick one random number, pick them all and then shuffle them as a whole.

Comment: yes sir! that was not added  properly. there is no error in syntax. this code is running. but numbers are repeating

Comment: How do i pick them as a whole and shuffle them @AlexHowansky

Comment: you need to reformat your code here, it doesn't make sense and shows as having more than one syntax error.

Comment: this post is beginning to look very unclear and very "broad", seeing new comments below. Well, I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array and then assign it to any session variable, for example:

```
$quizQuestions[] = $questionId;
$_SESSION['question'] = $quizQuestions;
```

In case you want to update the value, simply fetch it and assign new value and update it in the same variable again:

```
$quizQuestions = $_SESSION['question'];
$quizQuestions[] = $questionId;
$_SESSION['question'] = $quizQuestions;
```

Make sure that you have a session started first, add the following code to the very start of this script:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: how do i retrieve the column value , the column name is que_id

Comment: $quizQuestions=$_SESSION['que_id']; ????? like this

Comment: retrieving the value from session array?

Comment: no! retrieving the que_id from the database i meant. and putting it onto session

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a variable and unset it from the array of questions:

```
function get_question($questions)
{
    $question = rand($questions);
    $questionKey = array_search($question, $questions);

    unset($questions[$questionKey]);

    return $question;
}
```